# devexpress blazor popup component not opening after closing

Tags: blazor-server-side

I created a popup component and added it to my page. but after turning it on and off it won't turn back on. I couldn't understand this problem

Component

```
<DxPopup 
    @bind-Visible="@WarningPopupVisible"
    ShowFooter="true"
    HeaderText="Warning"
    BodyText="Content content content content"
    >
    <FooterContentTemplate>
        <DxButton CssClass="popup-button" RenderStyle="ButtonRenderStyle.Primary" Text="Tamam" Click="@(() => WarningPopupVisible = false)"/>
    </FooterContentTemplate>
</DxPopup>
@code {

    [Parameter]
    public bool WarningPopupVisible { get; set; } 

}

/productspage

<Warning WarningPopupVisible="WarningPopupVisible"/>

<DxButton Text="Open Modal" CssClass="w-25" Click="@(() => WarningPopupVisible = true)" />
@code {

public bool WarningPopupVisible { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you try to open an Popup from another class?

u need to reference to "WarningPopupVisible" dont initialize
"WarningPopupVisible" in /productpage again just use something like `popup.WarningPopUpVisible = false;`

and set the [Parameter] bool like this:

```
[Parameter]
public bool WarningPopupVisible { get; set; } = false;
```